# Visual Basic Compiler

Tags: vb.net

I need help fixing the `New` in this code:

```
 If (Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "Open your .ico file") Then
        New EthernalCompiler() With { _
            .Source = Me.txtSource.Text.Replace("3jkf0dks0", Me.txtPanelId.Text), _
            .Target = Target.Console, _
            .References = New String() { "System.dll", "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, _
            .Icon = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName _
        }.Compile(Me.txtFileName.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an icon", "Icon")
    End If
```

If anyone can fix this that would be great :)

Comment: what is going wrong? we need a lot more information as to what is going on, and what this application is supposed to be doing and such

Comment: The application is suppose to build another application, but there is a syntax error on the `New` in the code...

Comment: you really should supply the error code, and probably more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it like this:

```
Dim oCompiler as EthernalCompiler = New EthernalCompiler() With { _
            .Source = Me.txtSource.Text.Replace("3jkf0dks0", Me.txtPanelId.Text), _
            .Target = Target.Console, _
            .References = New String() { "System.dll", "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, _
            .Icon = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName _
        }.Compile(Me.txtFileName.Text)

oCompiler.Compile(Me.txtFileName.Text)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) Please mark as answered if solution was useful